# Socket Creation Compile Error using Winsock2 in c++

Tags: c++, sockets, compiler-errors, winsock2

EDIT :

```
#undef UNICODE

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "1016"

//Globals
struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
struct addrinfo hints;

//Prototypes
int listenFunction();
int acceptFunction(SOCKET ListenSocket);
```

I recently started recoding a tchat server that I never got to work in order to make a cleaner code but I ran in to an error that kinda confused me. I know how to fix this but I would like to know why it is doing this.
So basically, I have two functions, my main function :

```
int main()
{
    int iResult;
    std::cout << "At the begginning of main." << std::endl;
    WSADATA wsaData;

    //Initialize winsock
    std::cout << "Initializing winsock..." << std::endl;
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "WSAStartup failed." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "Sucess" << std::endl;

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    std::cout << "Going into listenFunction()" << std::endl;
    listenFunction();

    return 0;
}
```

And my listenFunction :

```
int listenFunction()
{
    int iResult;
    std::cout << "In Listening function" << std::endl;

    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    std::cout << "Calling addrinfo()" << std::endl;
    iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0){
        std::cout << "getaddrinfo() failed with error code : " << std::endl;
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    //Create a SOCKET for connecting to the server
    std::cout << "Creating ListenSocket..." << std::endl;
    ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        std::cout << "Socket failed with error : " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    //Maybe setsockopt function here if bug

    //Setup the TCP listening socket
    std::cout << "Setting up the TCP listening socket..." << std::endl;
    iResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        std::cout << "Bind failed with error : " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    std::cout << "Listening on ListenSocket..." << std::endl;
    //Listening
    iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR){
        std::cout << "Listen failed with error : " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    std::thread AcceptThread{ acceptFunction(ListenSocket) };

    return 0;
}
```

Bsically, when I declare the socket in the listenFunction, I get this error :

```
Error   1   error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
```

Where as if I copy that same exact line and paste it in the main function, I don't get that error anymore (of course I get all the errors in the listenFunction because its not declared). Is there anyway to fix this rather than passing it in an argument ?

Any help is greatly appreciated,

mindoo

Comment: Where are your header files?   I'm sure `SOCKET` is declared in one of them.

Comment: Is `listenFunction()` declared in the same file as `main()`?  You could be missing an include file...  Also, are there any other functions or variables called `ListenSocket' ?

Comment: Oh, sorry I forgot to put them. I'll add them in an edit.

Comment: Your last edit doesn't answer the question.  Where is this file `#include` -ed?  You can't just write a header file and not `#include` it anywhere.

Comment: @JPhi1618 ListenFunction is declared in the same file as main and I don't think that there is any other variable that is calle ListenSocket.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I didn't declare the function in another file thats why there isn't anything included.

Comment: @mindoo, So you're telling us that the module you're compiling consists *only* of those two functions, *and no other lines of code*?  No `#include "whatever.h"`?  No wonder you get the errors.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie no, thats not what I meant XD. All my includes are in my edit.

Comment: What I meant was that I didn't include any file that I wrote.

Comment: @mindoo, What we need to see is *where* you are including this header, not what the header consists of.  In other words, you should be editing your `main` function to see the `#include` directives at the top of that block of code.  Showing us the internals of an include module doesn't help.

Comment: Basically, if the line `SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;` is giving that error, it doesn't know what `INVALID_SOCKET` is.  Try to set the socket equal to zero and see what happens.  That's not a correct 'fix' but may help to troubleshoot.  Or change the variable name.  Or use a `int` instead of a SOCKET.  Just to narrow down the problem.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm not sure that I understand, in theory the winsock and all the headers that I have come with the visual studios IDE.

Comment: @mindoo http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e6e1a1bf2ac4139  Do you see that example?  Note how I #included those headers above `main` and my function?  That's what you should be showing.  Where in all of your posts so far have you done this?  Nowhere, up to this point.

Comment: Also, include WinSock _before_ windows.h.  I've seen many problems because of the include order.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes I did in my edit.

Comment: @mindoo, no you didn't.  You showed us the internals of a header file, but nowhere did you show us where you included this header file.  Yes, the header file itself consists of #include's, but where did you #include this header file in your `main` source file?  I think the issue is that you don't know where the include file is supposed to be placed.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I think the concatenation of all his code blocks is his one and only CPP file.  There are no self-written header files (if I understand).

Comment: If that's the case, then the `#undef UNICODE` is awfully suspicious to me.  Why undefine this constant?  It is used throughout the Windows definitions, AFAIK.

Comment: Looks like the `std::thread AcceptThread{ acceptFunction(ListenSocket) };` line is causing the error, not the socket creation.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm undefining unicode as it was something that I saw in my tutorial een though I didn't understand what I was doing so don't pay attention to that.

Answer (score 0):

The error you list is not caused by creating the socket, its caused by the line:

`std::thread AcceptThread{ acceptFunction(ListenSocket) };`

I'm not sure what you are trying to do there, as I am unfamiliar with how curly braces would be used to initialize a `std::thread`.  Maybe an attempt at a Lambda?

Comment: I'm trying to call that other function in a thread. There is no attempt to use a lambda, just a syntaxe error. I fixed the syntax error but it didn't help in solving my other error. The acceptFunction has only a return 0 statement, would that be creating the problem ?

Comment: So, you "fixed" it...  How?  Can you comment out that std::thread function and have the compile work?  Does it look like `std::thread AcceptThread( acceptFunction, ListenSocket);` now?

Comment: No I didn't fix it. I never had any errors with that line of code before, all I did was put parentethese instead of curly brackets. Thats what I meant by fix.

Comment: Ok, well using the syntax in my comment should fix it.  It compiles for me in VS2013.